# Discrete Fourier transform symmetry

Tags: discrete-signals, dft

I was reading the chapter on discrete Fourier transforms in Lyons' book -- Understanding Digital Signal Processing -- and could not understand the last paragraph about symmetry.

> There’s an additional symmetry property of the DFT that deserves mention at this point. In practice, we’re occasionally required to determine the DFT of real input functions where the input index $n$ is defined over both positive and negative values. If that real input function is even, then $X(m)$ is always real and even; that is, if the real $x(n) = x(−n)$, then, $X_{\textrm{real}}(m)$ is in general nonzero and $X_{\textrm{imag}}(m)$ is zero. Conversely, if the real input function is odd, $x(n) = −x(−n)$, then $X_{\textrm{real}}(m)$ is always zero and $X_{\textrm{imag}}(m)$ is, in general, nonzero.

Note: $X(m) = X_{\textrm{real}}(m) + jX_{\textrm{imag}}(m)$

- Firstly, what is meant by "odd" and "even"? I suspect it's the number of samples in the input signal, but that leads me to my second question,
- Why is $X_{\textrm{imag}}(m)$ zero with real input functions that are even, and why, with real input functions that are odd, is $X_{\textrm{real}}(m)$ zero and $X_{\textrm{imag}}(m)$ generally non-zero?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even_and_odd_functions

Comment: Yeah, after Hilmar's answer, I understood that's what the text was referring to.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Even & odd refer to the symmetry around $n = 0$.

Even means $x[n] = x[-n]$; you can get the part for $n < 0$ by simply mirroring the part for $n > 0$ at the $n=0$ line.

Odd means $x[n] = -x[-n]$; you can get the part for $n < 0$ by simply mirroring the part for $n > 0$ at the $n=0$ line and multiplying it by $-1$.

A cosine wave is even, sine wave is odd.

These are all just special cases of the general symmetry that says

> if it's real in one domain, it's conjugate symmetric in the other.

Conjugate symmetric means that the real part is even and the imaginary part is odd. Most people know that a real time domain signal as a conjugate symmetric spectrum, but it also goers the other way around: a conjugate symmetric time domain signal has a real valued spectrum.

Comment: Ah, picturing a cosine wave and sine wave helped me understand odd and even input functions. Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

Hilmar's answer is of course perfectly correct, but I think there there are several points that Lyons did not address in the statement quoted by the OP (or maybe he talked about them previously and chose not to repeat himself in the paragraph quoted by the OP).

The Discrete Fourier Transform (DFT) is commonly described as a transformation of 
a sequence $(x[0], x[1], \ldots, x[N-1])$ of finite length $N$
into another sequence $(X[0], X[1], \ldots, X[N-1])$ of length
$N$ where
$$\begin{align*}
X[m] &= \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} x[k]\exp\left(\frac{-j2\pi mk}{N}\right), 
~ m = 0, 1, \ldots, N-1,\\
x[n] &= \frac{1}{N}\sum_{m=0}^{N-1} X[m]\exp\left(\frac{j2\pi nm}{N}\right), 
~ n = 0, 1, \ldots, N-1.
\end{align*}$$
But these formulas can also be used when $m, n$ are outside the range 
$[0, N-1]$ and if we do so, we come to the conclusion that the length-$N$
DFT can be viewed as a  transformation from a *periodic* sequence $x[\cdot]$
to another *periodic* sequence $X[\cdot]$, both extending to infinity
in both directions, and that $(x[0], x[1], \ldots, x[N-1])$ and $(X[0], X[1], \ldots, X[N-1])$ are just *one period* of these infinitely long sequences.
Note that we are insisting that $x[n+iN] = x[n]$ and $X[m+iN] = X[m]$ for
all $m, n,$ and $i$.

This is, of course, not how data are often handled in practice. We may have
a very long sequence of samples, and we break them up into blocks
of suitable length $N$.  We calculate the DFT of $(x[0], x[1], \ldots, x[N-1])$  as
$$X^{(0)}[m] = \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} x[k]\exp\left(\frac{-j2\pi mk}{N}\right), 
~ m = 0, 1, \ldots, N-1,$$
the DFT of the next chunk $(x[N], x[N+1], \ldots, x[2N-1])$  as
$$X^{(1)}[m] = \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} x[k+N]\exp\left(\frac{-j2\pi mk}{N}\right), 
~ m = 0, 1, \ldots, N-1,$$
the  DFT of the previous chunk $(x[-N], x[-N+1], \ldots, x[-1])$  as
$$X^{(-1)}[m] = \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} x[k-N]\exp\left(\frac{-j2\pi mk}{N}\right), 
~ m = 0, 1, \ldots, N-1,$$
etc. and then we play with these various DFTs of the various chunks
into which we have subdivided our data.  Of course, if the data 
are in fact periodic with period $N$, all these DFTs will be the same.

Now, when Lyons
talks of *...where the input index n is defined over both positive and negative values...* he is talking of the *periodic* case, and when he says that
a (real) even function has the property 
$x[n] = x[-n]$, this property must hold for **all** integers $n$.
Since periodicity also applies, we have not only that $x[-1] = x[1]$
but $x[-1] = x[-1+N] = x[N-1]$, and similarly, $x[-n] = x[n] = x[N-n]$.
In other words, the *real even sequence* $(x[0], x[1], \ldots, x[N-1])$ whose
DFT is a real even sequence (as stated by Lyons and explained very
nicely by Hilmar) is *necessarily* of the form
$$(x[0], x[1], \ldots, x[N-1])
= (x[0], x[1], x[2], x[3], \ldots, x[3], x[2], x[1])$$
which is (apart from the leading $x[0]$) a *palindromic* sequence.
If you are partitioning your data into blocks of length $N$
and computing the DFT of each block separately, then these
separate DFTs will *not* have the symmetry properties
described above unless the DFT is of a block with this
palindromic property.

Answer (score 1):

Just for even and odd function clarification,

Even : symmetric with respect to y axis
Odd:   symmetric with respect to origin

And without going into mathematical details, DFT of real valued function is symmetric, i.e. resultant  Fourier function has both real and imaginary parts which are mirror images with respect to 0 frequency component. This doesn't happen in case where you take DFT of a complex function.

Comment: >Even : symmetric with respect to y axis Odd: symmetric with respect to origin.  Could you explain just a little bit more what this means, perhaps giving examples of functions that you consider to be even function and odd respectively? I get the feeling that maybe your definition allows a function to be both even and odd.  Is that so?

Comment: Hi Dilip, If a function is mirror image with respect to y axis, its even. For example, cosine is mirror image with respect to Y axis. Its an even function. For odd function, its a reflection with respect to origin. Means you take reflection with respect to both X and Y. Like sine function. You can just look at the plot and tell if its an even or odd function.